# NextJS Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting the following errors in my nextjs application:

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

In the console:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
    at div
    at SendTransaction
    at div
    at MyApp (webpack-internal:///./pages/_app.tsx:39:11)
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:62:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:301:63)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:850:919)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:62:1)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:172:11)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:347:11)
```

I am doing the tutorial on wagmi found here: https://wagmi.sh/examples/send-transaction

My file structure is as such:
comps/transaction.tsx (This is scaled back to as simple as I could make it and it still throws these errors).

```
import * as React from 'react';

 
export function SendTransaction() {

   return <h1>TEST!</h1>
      
}
```

pages/index.tsx

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { ConnectKitButton } from 'connectkit';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          height: '100vh',
        }}
      >
      <ConnectKitButton />
    </div>
    
  );
};

export default Home;
```

pages/_app.tsx

```
import { WagmiConfig, createClient, useAccount, useConnect, useDisconnect } from 'wagmi';
import { mainnet, polygon, optimism, arbitrum } from 'wagmi/chains';
import { ConnectKitProvider, getDefaultClient } from 'connectkit';
import { SendTransaction } from '../comps/transaction';
import React from 'react';


const client = createClient(
  getDefaultClient({
    appName: 'ConnectKit Next.js demo',
    //infuraId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INFURA_ID,
    //alchemyId:  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ALCHEMY_ID,
    chains: [mainnet, polygon, optimism, arbitrum],
  })
);


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { isConnected } = useAccount();
  if (isConnected) {
    return (
        <div>
             {/* Account content goes here */}
             <SendTransaction />
        </div>
    )
  }
  
  return (
        <WagmiConfig client={client}>
            <ConnectKitProvider>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ConnectKitProvider>
        </WagmiConfig>
    
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

In the above, pages/_app.tsx, if i remove:

```
const { isConnected } = useAccount();
  if (isConnected) {
    return (
        <div>
             {/* Account content goes here */}
             <SendTransaction />
        </div>
    )
  }
```

It works just fine. I am new to react and nextjs, and I have been pulling my hair out over this problem for a while now.

I have looked here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
(As well as other stackoverflow articles and other documentation)
And I cannot figure out why this hydration error is occurring, especially since my component is so simple. The warning: Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in . Makes no sense as all of my tags seem to be matching up. I am thinking I need to use useEffect for something but cannot figure out what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is my package.json just in case:
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connectkit": "^1.1.3",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "next": "^13.1.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3",
    "use-debounce": "^9.0.3",
    "wagmi": "^0.10.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/react": "18.0.27",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const { isConnected } = useAccount();
  const loading = (
        <div>
           <SendTransaction />
        </div>
  );
  
  return (
        <WagmiConfig client={client}>
            <ConnectKitProvider>
               {isConnected ?(loading) : (<Component {...pageProps} />)} 
            </ConnectKitProvider>
        </WagmiConfig>   
  );
}
```

Comment: I moved forward in the tutorial, and started getting the same error again. I am posting here to save people some grief. Each time you edit and save, reloading the server, you must disconnect your wallet. After you do this and load things work out.

Comment: if you check the console you can see what is causing the error